# Swiper JS for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, swiper.js

as I already found great help here in the community, I thought I'd post my question here, maybe there'd be somebody who could help me.

I am creating my websites in wordpress and found a great tool for creating an image carousel. As I am more of an intermediate in wordpress and mainly working with plugins, I found the swiper JS plugin in the wordpress plugin directory. It works fine but I have the problem that it won't loop and you can't get to the first and last image of the carousel, it always snaps back to the second and second to last image.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/swiper-js-slider/

This is the one I am using right now.

My question also is how I can use the Swiper JS in wordpress without using the plugin. I want to have it specifically on one page and it should be mobile friendly. All the design that already is on the page should be remain as it is. Would there be a possibility to include the Swiper Js tool even though I am using a wordpress theme?

Thank you so so much, it is really hugely appreciated!

Linda

Only worked with the plugin so far, no css helped...

Answer (score 0):

Using WP custom code.
We assume your words "the plugin" are about that exact SwiperJS plugin.
Have you considered using an iFrame? See lower web links.
An iframe will allow you to add a video, audio, images, etc., so presumably even a slider lands in that category. Try this avenue first to see if it works for your needs. Read about WP iframe use in the links below.

```
<iframe src="test7.html" width="600" height="300" style="border:1px solid black;" title=""></iframe>
```

Or...
Other snippet plugin options exist (read developer docs). There are pro/con to some of those options (i.e. time, etc). Read developer resources (from an WP admin perspective) for more ideas.

[wordpress iframe](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/)

[kinsta article](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-iframe/)

[WP developers articles](https://developer.wordpress.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have just discovered that the theme I am using has the same possibilities to use the coverflow (have not known this before) so instead of the plugin, I am using the theme slider now. Thank you so much for the code nonetheless, I hope I can use it in the future :)

Linda